# Firebase reading data from AutoId node Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, snapshot

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase with this hierarchy:

[image: Firebase Hierarchy]

Now i want to access data of autoId which I'm doing like this:

```
let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child("\(jobID)")
        ref.observe(.value, with: {
            (snapshot) in

            if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

                for child in result{
                    let autoId = child.key as String
                    let newRef = ref.child("\(autoId)")
                    newRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                        (snapshot2) in
                        let model = snapshot2.value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
                        })
                      }
                    }
             }
```

jobID is 0 here.
But it is not going inside the closure of newRef.observeSingleEvent() I don't know why. Path is also correct I've checked it by debugging and printing newRef in each loop.

Comment: In your code, ref points to the node `-MA660...` and loads EVERYTHING in that node, including all of the child data. There's no reason to have another observe. You just need to access the child nodes from the snapshot. But, more importantly, it appears you're using an array (?) within chats. That's going to cause headaches long term. In Firebase Real Time Database, if you're using an array, you're probably doing it wrong as there are usually much better alternatives. See [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why complicate your query when you could use `.observeSingleEvent()`?

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap : DataSnapshot)  in
    for child in snap.children {
        let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String

        // Use the keys however you like
    }
}) { (err: Error) in
    print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
}
```